# Decode WebTarget URI

Tags: java, jsp, uri, encode

I have one property in property file

```
appointments.deleteAppointmentwithReasonApi=api/appointment/{id}?reason={reason}
URL=http://xyz/etc/
```

in another file

```
public static final String  DELETE_APPOINTMENT_REASON = PropertiesUtil.getPropertyValueFromKey(REST_WEBSERVICE_URLS_PROP_FILE,
            "appointments.deleteAppointmentwithReasonApi"); // To get API name
public static final String URL = ServicesUtil.getURL(); // to get endpoint URL
```

In my java API call, I gave something like this

```
WebTarget target = client.target(CommonConstants.URL)
                    .path(CommonConstants.DELETE_APPOINTMENT_REASON)
                    .resolveTemplate("id", appointmentID).resolveTemplate("reason", reason);
            System.out.println(target);
```

My response is printing like this...

```
JerseyWebTarget { http://xyz/etc/api/appointment/abc-123-ced-456%3Freason=Test }
```

which is not hitting the proper Web Services...I want it to be like this

```
JerseyWebTarget { http://xyz/etc/api/appointment/abc-123-ced-456?reason=Test }
```

I know i need to encode URL. I am not able to do it somehow. Any suggestion ?